# Any one know how i can make this Animation or what is the library

Tags: animation, scroll

how to make this animation mobile move from rotate 45 deg to 90 deg to Section two  when i scroll[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8rUj.gif)

I try make this animation and i didn't know  anyone know how made it this
thank you for your solving